# C# - Excel - Office Interop - Exception HRESULT 0x80010100 (RPC_E_SYS_CALL_FAILED)

Tags: c#, office-interop

I have a Windows forms application that runs an excel macro using Office Interop.
I run the macro from the main GUI thread but the macro is pretty long to run and after several minutes it ends up in an exception RPC_E_SYS_CALL_FAILED.

Any ideas?

Exception is : System call failed. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80010100 (RPC_E_SYS_CALL_FAILED))

My code :

```
    // Excel Objects
    Excel.Application xlApp = null;
    Excel.Workbook xlWorkBookMacro = null;
    Excel.Workbook xlWorkBookBilan = null;

    try
    {
        // Open Excel
        xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

        // Open Workbooks
        xlWorkBookMacro = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(Properties.Settings.Default.PathToMacroBilan);
        xlWorkBookBilan = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(Path.Combine(Folder, Filename));

        // Run Macro
        xlApp.Run(MacroName, Filename, DateBilan.AddHours(HEURE_DEBUT_BILAN).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"), int.Parse(ScheduleRec["no_batch"].ToString()), int.Parse(ScheduleRec["no_oper"].ToString()), int.Parse(ScheduleRec["type_activ"].ToString()), Path.Combine(RepertoireEnrSous, EnrSous), ScheduleRec["edition"].ToString(), ScheduleRec["imprimante"].ToString(), ScheduleRec["orientation"].ToString());

        // Close Workbooks
        xlWorkBookBilan.Close(true);
        xlWorkBookMacro.Close(false);

        // Close Excel
        xlApp.Quit();

        // Clean Excel Objects
        ReleaseExcelObject(xlApp);
        ReleaseExcelObject(xlWorkBookBilan);
        ReleaseExcelObject(xlWorkBookMacro);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        TraceLogger.WriteLog(String.Format("Exception : {0}", ex.Message));
    }
```

Comment: Post exception details. Post your code.

Comment: Exception details and code posted...

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution in adding a DoEvents in the main loop of my macro.